# Do I need the Tensorflow Object Detection API to use a trained model I made on a different computer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object, package, detection

Working on my local computer, I've created a Tensorflow Object Detector. I have exported the model (which I've tested using the checkpoints) to a protobuf file as well as several others (TF lite, TF js, etc). I now need to transfer this trained model to another computer that doesn't have the Object Detection API or other things I needed to build the model.

Do I need all these dependencies on the new machine? Or, does the protobuf file contain everything that the machine will need? The new machine only has the basic anaconda environment packages as well as tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf files most commonly contains both model and weights. So in theory you can load your model on any machine with TensorFlow.

The only problem that I can think of is saving custom layers/losses/optimizers and data pre/postprocessing.